# One target page for all ajax calls or one for each

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, call, echo

If I have two (or more) ajax calls on my page, ajax1 and ajax2, do I make one general target url ajax.php that conditionally returns a string, or do I make a target php page per call, ajax1.php and ajax2.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use only one main PHP script to handle all of your AJAX calls and simply append an extra parameter to your request specifying what response you require.

```
$.post('/ajaxResponser.php',{'method':'getData','user_id':'123'},function(response){
  // handle response
},"json");
```

Then in your `ajaxResponser.php` you would decide what method to call according to the `method` parameter that was passed -

```
$method = $_REQUEST['method'];
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
switch($method){
  case 'getData':
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>getData($user_id)));
  break;
  default:
    echo json_encode(array('err'=>'unknown method'));
  break;
}
```

Comment: What would be best practice? One target page or many?

Comment: That all depends on your logic and the actual methods you are using.  If you have many many methods to call you might want to consider splitting them into multiple files.  One for user actions, one news, one for online users.... Just some examples... A best practice would be to ensure that if you have multiple target pages - that their names will be meaningful; The same goes for the method names.  It all depends on what you are doing... Make sure that the next programmer that comes to look at your code can easily understand where each method is located and in what file...

Answer (score 2):

simply make one php page and in your all ajax functions make a flag variable in data string like "&ajax1="+"1" and on php page use if condition like

```
if($_REQUEST['ajax1']){
 your code
  }
 if($_REQUEST['ajax2']){
 your code
  }
```